# How can we say that $\exp^{(jt)}$ is an eigenfuntion in frequency domain?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, eigenfunctions

In  this question and its solution, I don't understand how to solve part $b$,$c$ and $d$ by saying directly $\exp^{(jt)}$ is a eigenfunction. How can we directly multiply with time domain function and function with Fourier transform? Can you explain it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't see the image. Can you add it as a formula instead? exp(jt) is not an eigenfunction to the Fourier transform as an operator, but it is to the differential operator which the Fourier transform diagonalizes.

Comment: I couldn't write a formulation because I don't know  how to write formula as a code here .I can share bigger image .

Comment: Ok there is a tutorial for formula writing in MathJax somewhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials <-- you can read about the orthogonal basis of eigenfunctions to the Fourier transform under "Hermite functions as eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform"

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference <--- typesetting tutorial

Comment: Thanks  @mathreadler